# Scale Animation of Image

Tags: android, image, android-animation

I am new to Android, I am developing a simple and small app, which contains a scale animation on the home page. I have been trying to get it to work for last week but I haven't managed to get the expected output.

I am using the following code, but the result I get is as if I am getting the animation from the side of the Image (bottom to top), however, I want to center animation (From bottom to top).

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.animationimage);
ScaleAnimation scale = new ScaleAnimation((float) 1.0, (float) 1.5, (float) 1.0, (float) 1.5);
scale.setFillAfter(true);
scale.setDuration(700);
imageView.startAnimation(scale);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May this help you:

Use,

```
 ScaleAnimation animation = new ScaleAnimation(fromXscale, toXscale, fromYscale, toYscale, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float)0.5, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, (float)0.5);
```

Comment: Should use 0.5f instead (float)0.5